# SQL Error 18456 al conectarme al servidor

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy teniendo problemas para conectarme con "SQL Sever Authentication".

Cuando instalé el programa en la parte de *Database Engine Configuration* seleccioné modo de autenticación mixta, esto me creo un administrador "CRONOPIO\Lucas(Lucas)" pero al querer logearme desde el SQL obtengo el error:

> Cannot connect to CRONOPIO.
>   Login failed for user 'Cronopio\Lucas' . (Microsoft SQL Sever Error: 18456.

Probé también loguearme usando simplemente "Lucas" pero aun así obtengo el error. No hay problemas al loguearme con la autenticación de Windows pero necesito realizar un trabajo y es necesario loguearse con el de SQL.

**Update:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para conectarte en modo `SQL Sever Authentication`, debes usar un *login* que fue creado para ese modo.

El administrador (`CRONOPIO\Lucas(Lucas)`) que fue creado al instalar la base de datos debe ser de tipo *Windows Authentication*. Puedes verificar esto al mirar las propiedades de ese *login* (`Security --> Logins`). No puedes usar este *login* para loguearte en modo `SQL Sever Authentication`.

Lo que necesitas es crear un nuevo *login* creado específicamente para `SQL Sever Authentication`. Para esto, ve a `Security --> Logins`, y haz `New Login...`. Allí, asegúrate de escoger `SQL Sever Authentication`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo que instalarlo de nuevo entonces? O como llego A esa ventana? Tengo SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: No necesitas instalarlo de nuevo. No sé exactamente como se hace en SQL Server 2008 R2, yo tengo SQL Server 2016, pero la idea debe ser similar. Tienes que buscar el nodo "Security" en la parte izquierda del programa, y de allí debes conseguir la opcion que te permite crear un nuevo "Login". La ventana que te salga probablemente no va a ser igualito al mío, pero debe ser muy parecido.

Comment: Has salvado a mi corazon de un paro. Muchas gracias! Abrazos y exitos.